# Subquery, SQL Group By

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, sum, subquery

I`m following and example give in Coursera course SQL for Data Science, this is the example:

```
Select customer_name 
      ,customer_state      
      (Select Count (*) AS orders      
      FROM Orders     
      Where Orders.customer_id = Customer.customer_id) AS orders 
From customers
Order By Customer_name
```

So I try to apply the same logic to my Chinook DB using this query:

```
Select FirstName
      ,State        
      (Select Count (*) As invoices       
      From invoices       
      Where invoices.CustomerId = customers.CustomerId) As Orders
From Customers
Order by Firstname
```

But it seems like I`m making a mistake as SQLite wont even let me run it Do you have any idea why?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Literally it wont even let me run it, theres a green execute button that stays gray I cant even click on it

Comment: It sounds like something else is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Missing comma before subquery.

so the syntax will be error.

```
Select customer_name 
      ,customer_state      
      ,(Select Count (*) AS orders      
      FROM Orders     
      Where Orders.customer_id = Customer.customer_id) AS orders 
From customers
Order By Customer_name
```